# I can't center more than one widget in stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use stack for some reason and all my widgets should be centered. It's ok when I use one positioned and one align. However using second align widget does not place under the first text.

```
Widget _body() {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        child: Text("Text here"),
      ),
      Align(
        child: Text(
          "First Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        child: Text(
          "Second Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

I want to reach this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iko87.png)

Comment: Will `Positioned` work for you or you only wanna go with `Align`?

Comment: Everything works for me I don't want it to be written with fixed pixel values.

Comment: I think you the better way is to use `Align` and you should give a fixed value there however if you don't like fixed approach, the best way is to use `Column`.

Comment: If I use column then I can't use a sizedTransition animation.

Comment: Can you give me the whole screen you want to implement, I'll try my best to provide you the best possible solution.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: Did the solution work? Please let me know if you have further issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Widget _buildBody() {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.95),
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.jpg', width: 200, height: 200, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.35),
        child: Text("Centered Text"),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.1),
        child: Text("Second centered text"),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.1),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want. However I need to think what about image size right now :) It should be automatically calculate the fraction depending on image size. Using static hard-coded values can cause problems.

Comment: You are using images from assets so I think it won't be an issue to hard code it, if you were to use `Image.network()`, then the trick part would be to use `LayoutBuilder` then. However you should be good to go with hard coded value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with `Align` here is what you need.

```
Widget _body() {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Text("Text here"),
      ),
      Align(
        child: Text(
          "Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.1), // change this value to place it below the 1st centered widget
        child: Text(
          "Second Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

[image]